# Speech-to-text in Android

Tags: android, speech-to-text

I want to learn the speech-to-text conversion in Android. Please let me know if any tutorials link you know. Or tell me how to achieve this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Voice Recognization](http://www.vogella.com/code/de.vogella.android.apitest/src/com/example/android/apis/app/VoiceRecognition.html) might help you.

Comment: [This](http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=6&number=185) tutorial is just what you're looking for. Further more, you can always ask questions about what part you didnt understand.

Answer (score 0):

Try App Inventor for Android. It has a functionality that converts text to speech and vice versa. Link to App Inventor is http://www.appinventor.mit.edu . It is easy to learn and work with App Inventor.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the ApiDemos: `com.example.android.apis.app/TextToSpeechActivity.java`